# How to keep IP trust from email companies when developing in local/test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, sendgrid

I am using sendgrid on my Rails app that I am beginning to build.
I am in test mode, mostly doing local stuff but I send many emails to check my process or email layout.

The email I use to receive the emails is on Gmail. I fear Gmail will see there are many  emails everyday and never an answer and maybe that the CSS changes a lot, and maybe other factors gmail take into account to assess the trust level of an IP sending emails...

Do I risk Gmail to decrease the trust level of my sendgrid IP? (I don't have much choice during test mode I think)?

What could I do to avoid the IP trust getting hit?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [mailtrap](http://mailtrap.io/pages/faq) to avoid polluting true email addresses. You may check emails sent from their web interface or manually forward them to your inbox.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [mailcatcher](http://mailcatcher.me/) to catch and view your emails sent from localhost.

```
MailCatcher runs a super simple SMTP server which catches any message
sent to it to display in a web interface. Run mailcatcher, set your
favourite app to deliver to smtp://127.0.0.1:1025 instead of your
default SMTP server, then check out http://127.0.0.1:1080 to see the
mail that's arrived so far.
```

In order for you to use it:

1. gem install mailcatcher
2. mailcatcher
3. Go to http://localhost:1080/